# retrieve data from xml and display it in html

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xquery

I am working on XML for first time and would highly appreciate help to solve my problem. I have tried few things but it didn't work to retrieve data from XML.

I have XML of following type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<search>
  <criterias>
    <criteria operator="EqualTo" xmlpath="//Title/TitleKey">
      <value1>1</value1>
    </criteria>
    <criteria operator="EqualTo" xmlpath="//Title/SubTitleKey">
      <value1>1</value1>
    </criteria>
    <freecriteria operator="EqualTo" xmlpath="//UseMaxRowsToReturn">
      <value1>1</value1>
    </freecriteria>
    <criteria operator="Contains" xmlpath="//Title/TitleReference" >
      <value1>001</value1>
      <desc>Title referenece</desc></criteria>
    <criteria operator="Contains"  xmlpath="//Title/TitleFamily/TitleReference">
      <value1>Title number</value1>
    </criteria>
  </criterias>
</search>
```

I want retrieve value which is ' 001' which is in XML. I want put them as a hyperlink in HTML. In short I want display it in the HTML page. I have created XSL file but it didn't retrieve the value. I am trying x-query for e.g

```
             <html>
              <body>
                <h1>Search</h1>
                <ul>
                {
                  for $x in doc("Titlesearch.xml")//Title/TitleReference
                  order by $x/TitleReference
                  return <li>< a href:"a.txt">{data($x/TitleReference)}. Title: {data          
                      ($x/@Title)}</a>
                   </li>
                 }
                </ul>
               </body>
               </html>
```

but it is not generating any result, not even a html `<h1>`
I have used below xslt too. 
    enter code here

### Application Search

Title Reference
                        Title Family

```
               <td><a><xsl:value-of select="//Title/TitleReference"/></a></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="="//Title/TitleFamily/TitleReference"/></td>
                   </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
                  </table>
                  </body>
                  </html>
                   </xsl:template>
                 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What you show is not an XSLT stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath syntax does not at all match the XML you are using as the input document. The attributes `xmlpath` are just strings, they do not imply any sort of XPath. The XPath's that you need should navigate the source document.

As your XPath's do not match your XML document at all, it is hard to know what you are trying to achieve exactly. However, for example, perhaps you may actually be trying to do something like the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <ul>
        {
            for $x in doc("Titlesearch.xml")/search/criterias/criteria[@operator eq "Contains"][@xmlpath eq "//Title/TitleReference"]
            order by $x/value1
            return 
                <li>
                    <a href="{$x/value1}.txt">Title: {$x/value1/text()}</a>
                </li>
        }
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I would note that depending on the XQuery processor you are using, you may need to provide an absolute URI in the argument to `doc`, which locates your `Titlesearch.xml`, e.g.

```
doc("file:/some/path/on/your/computer/Titlesearch.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try your method and let you know.

Comment: It didnt display result but displayed the html as below

Comment: Search
for $x in doc("Titlesearch.xml")/search/criterias/criteria[@operator eq "Contains"][@xmlpath eq "//Title/TitleReference"] { order by $x/value1 return 
Title: {$x/value1/text()} }

Comment: what if by using xslt . I have created xslt as shown above but it didnt retrieve any value

Comment: I tested the above using the Saxon 9 processor from oXygen XML Editor and I tend to trust it. So I I suspect if you are not seeing the same results as me, the problem is not with the XQuery code I have provided but something else. When I run my XQuery above, I get this output:
`
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Search</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="001.txt">Title: 001</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>`

Comment: I have used the same x-query which you have provided. I am not getting any result is it because xml file has same tags with different xmlpath string.

Comment: you can try this solution live at http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/7nEmSDGUPQa6LNTsyZC45BhPSnM%3D and the serialized html result: http://tryzorba.28.io/query.jq?id=7nEmSDGUPQa6LNTsyZC45BhPSnM%3D&format=html

Comment: @user2897967 Which XQuery processor did you test this with? If you used Saxon, did you change the URI passed to the `doc` function to point correctly at the location of your source document? I used the XML document that you posted at the start of your question as the source document `Titlesearch.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an XSLT processor to run your `XSL`. Have a look at the following depending where you want to run the processor:

- client-side: [Saxon Client Edition](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) ;
- server-side: [Saxon 9.x](http://www.saxonica.com/) or [Xalan](https://xalan.apache.org/).

Comment: I have used xml notepad and transform xml but generates only html result not the xml data in it. I have used this xsl for that